# Jasper Exception

Tags: java, jsp

Error:

> /org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration_1.jsp at line 19

Code:

```
16:     
17: PersonalInfoBO_1 obj = new PersonalInfoBO_1();
18: 
19: String empId = obj.setempId();
20: request.setAttribute("empId",empId );
21:     String refid= (String)request.getAttribute("refid");
22:     String gender, department;
```

Comment: post the declaration of `setempId()` or the class `PersonalInfoBO_1`

Comment: The complete stacktrace will be needed

Comment: And also setter method cant be `Null` in any case

Comment: Look at this method `PersonalInfoBO_1#setempId()`. What is return type? What you want to set here?

Comment: Which exception? See logs.